# Nested Loop Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need your help in nexted VBA loop. I have some data in two columns and blank rows between rows. This macro loop through a column and find out if it contain certain character. If it' blank then I want it to move to next row. If it contain "Den", then select a specific worksheet ("D-Temp") else select ("M-Temp").
After selecting right Worksheet, it need to fill up text boxs with data from 2nd column as per Row no. The code I have created so far is

```
Sub Template()

    Dim j As Long
    Dim c As Range, t As Range
    Dim ws As String

    j = 5
    With Sheets("Sample ")
        For Each c In .Range("I3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
            If c.Value = "" Then
                Next ' `Not getting how to jump to next one`
            ElseIf c.Value = "DEN" Then
                ws = "D-Temp"
            Else
                ws = "M-Temp"
            End If

        For Each t In .Range("P3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
            If t.Value <> "" Then
                j = j + 1
                Sheets("M-Temp").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = t.Value
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = t.Offset(, -1).Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    End With
```

Any help ??
Below is the sample Data I have :

```
Type    Name 1  Name2
DEN     Suyi    Nick
                     'Blank row'
PX      Mac     Cruise
```

I want macro to Identify Type & select template worksheet (D or M) as per that and fill textboxes on that template with Name 1 & Name2 respectively.

Comment: I believe you just need to say "Next j" instead of "Next". You need to specificy which variable it should affect.

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking of something else.

Comment: Beg your pardon, but what's the point in filling ***same*** textbox with different values in a loop?

Comment: @JohnyL There are two text boxes on each template. I want macro to filled those text boxes with name1 & name 2 as per Type.

Comment: @prashant Oops, my bad... Now I see. When you copy, a new sheet is active sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you're after this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Template()
    Dim c As Range

    With Sheets("Sample")
        For Each c In .Range("I3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through referenced sheet column C not empty cells form row 3 down to last not empty one
            Worksheets(IIf(c.Value = "DEN", "D-Temp", "M-Temp")).Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' create copy of proper template: it'll be the currently "active" sheet
            With ActiveSheet ' reference currently "active" sheet
                .Shapes("Textbox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = c.Offset(, 7).Value ' fill referenced sheet "TextBox 1" shape text with current cell (i.e. 'c') offset 7 columns (i.e. column "P") value
                .Shapes("Textbox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = c.Offset(, 6).Value ' fill referenced sheet "TextBox 2" shape text with current cell (i.e. 'c') offset 6 columns (i.e. column "O") value
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @prashant, any feedback?

Comment: Sorry to delay in response. Your code is working perfectly fine the way I want to. just one small thing. You have used .Specialcells(xlCellTypeConstants) to omit blank cells. However it's still considering those cells. Any idea how to correct it ??

Comment: I got this now with a simple tweak in you code. Thanks a lot for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mis-understanding your current nesting...

```
With Sheets("Sample ")
    For Each c In .Range("I3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))

        If c.Value <> "" Then
            If c.Value = "DEN" Then
                ws = "D-Temp"
            Else
                ws = "M-Temp"
            End If
            For Each t In .Range("P3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
                If t.Value <> "" Then
                    j = j + 1
                    Sheets("M-Temp").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = t.Value
                    ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = t.Offset(, -1).Value
                End If
            Next
        End if 'not blank
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your code is skipping blank rows  and creating template. But I want this to fill textbox as per that specific row value. I have mention sample data in question. Let me know If I am clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, correctly, you need to change your if/then logic slightly:

```
Sub Template()

    Dim j As Long
    Dim c As Range, t As Range
    Dim ws As String

    j = 5
    With Sheets("Sample ")
        For Each c In .Range("I3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
            If c.Value <> "" Then
                If c.Value = "DEN" Then
                    ws = "D-Temp"
                    Exit For
                Else
                    ws = "M-Temp"
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        For Each t In .Range("P3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp))
            If t.Value <> "" Then
                j = j + 1
                Sheets("M-Temp").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = t.Value
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox 2").TextFrame.Characters.Text = t.Offset(, -1).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

You might want to add code to make sure that ws is set to something (not all columns were blank).

Comment: the above code is creating "D" template only inspite of value in "I" column. I have edited my question with sample data. Let me know if it's clear enough.